# Apply polar change of coordinates to $(x^2+y^2)^2y''=(x+yy')^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

The task is to apply polar change to the equation: $(x^2+y^2)^2y''=(x+yy')^3$. I've solved easy problems in class such as $y'=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$, where the derivative is just on one side and it's of the first order. There simply I assume that $y=y(x)$ and $x=r\cos{\varphi}$ and $y=r\sin{\varphi}$ $\Longrightarrow y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}dr+\frac{\partial y}{\partial\varphi}d\varphi}{\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}dr+\frac{\partial x}{\partial\varphi}d\varphi}=\frac{\cos{\varphi}-\sin{\varphi}}{\cos{\varphi}+\sin{\varphi}}$
I'd like to use the same trick in this problem as well, but I don't even know where to start from! Should I expand the brackets before or after replacing $y'$ with $\frac{dy}{dx}$? The idea is to simplify the differential equation, not to solve it (I haven't studied that yet). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change coordinates you have to remember that $r=r(x,y),\, \varphi=\varphi(x,y)$.
You can now plug in the substitution $x=r \mathrm{sin}\varphi,\, y=r\mathrm{cos}\varphi$ and obtain
\begin{align}
r^4\left(\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2}\mathrm{sin}\varphi+r\frac{\partial^2\mathrm{sin}\varphi}{\partial x^2}\right)=\left(r\mathrm{cos}\varphi+r\mathrm{sin}\varphi\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\mathrm{sin}\varphi+r\frac{\partial\mathrm{sin}\varphi}{\partial x}\right)\right)^3
\end{align}

Comment: I must have been blind! Thank you.